# AJAX request on enter key in textarea not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Whenever I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key it doesn't seem to post it just goes to the next line. I tried it with the `alert` option it does work but when i post something it doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.comment').keydown(function (e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var post_id = $(this).attr('post_id');
            var comment = $(this).val();
            $.post('/comment.php', { post_id: post_id, comment: comment });
        }
    });
});
```

Index.php:

```
<div class='comment_type_area'>
    <textarea class='comment' post_id='<?php $shared_id2; ?>' id='text_comment' placeholder='Write a Comment'></textarea>
    <button id='post_button' type='button'>Post</button>
```

comment.php

```
 include 'sqlconnect.php';
 $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
 $comment = $_POST['comment'];
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `comment_system` 
 (`id`, `user_id`, `post_id`, `first_name`, `date_time`, `comment`) 
 VALUES (NULL, '1', '$post_id', '', '', '$comment')");
```

How can I make the button and also the enter key post somthing? I can't seem to figure it out. Please help.

Comment: From what you describe the problem lays with the AJAX request to `comment.php`, not the JS code. Check the network tab of the console to find exactly what the error is. Posting the code of `comment.php` here would also help.

Comment: Check your syntax for post

Comment: okay let me post the comment.php

Comment: There's your issue. If you need further help I would suggest editing your question to include the `comment.php` file, otherwise you should delete this question.

Comment: **Why** don't you use `input` element??? Changing default behaviour of a textarea could easily disturb your users

Comment: Please include the comment.php

Comment: okay i included comment.php

Comment: Where is the `top` property used? Have you included line 75 of the file?

Comment: there is no line 75 in the jquery file also in comment.php

Comment: There is not Console Error anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix it my error was in 
`index.php`

**Index.php**

```
 <div id='comment_type_area' class='comment_type_area'>
            <form method='POST'>
                <input type='text' class='comment' post_id='<?php $shared_id2; ?>' id='text_comment' placeholder='Write a Comment'></input>
                <input type='submit' id='post_button' ></input> 
            </form>
```

I missed out the method part and also changed the text area to input

thanks for all your peoples input